# Zend Website Processing Time

Tags: php, performance, zend-framework

I have a web site developed using Zend Framework. Mainly I am using MVC architecture and couple of Zend libraries. Once I host the site on the server I noticed that it takes considerable time to load the page. Specially the processing time. It take sometime to start responding for the HTTP request. I used Zend auto loader.

```
$autoLoader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoLoader->registerNamespace('Classes_');
$autoLoader->registerNamespace('Crypt_');
$autoLoader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
```

It's still considerably slow. MyDB is indexed for require fields. Someone please suggest me a way to get rid of this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Profile your app, for example with XDebug.

Comment: Are you using a PHP accelerator or cache?

Comment: I am using none of them. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. It works well.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/performance.classloading.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Zend's library : Zend_Optimizer.
It will increase the response time.

for guidance there is link:
[Zend_optimizer](http://www.webhostgear.com/184.html) and [Zend_optimizer install](http://www.debiantutorials.com/installing-zend-optimizer/)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [Zend_Cache](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.introduction.html) then it will be one of the best way after certain level of Optimisation. Have a look into [Zend_Cache_Frontend_Page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.frontends.html#zend.cache.frontends.page)